# why the width of the bar of victory is so small?

Tags: victory-charts

`My fiddle:` https://jsfiddle.net/xuhang1128/uynsnryr/9/.

even I set below parameter to VictoryBar, it still not work. thanks.

style={{
          data: {
            strokeWidth: 15
         }
        }}

Comment: When the system says that you should copy-paste the code in the question, it really means it. Don't go around the rule by code-highlighting random words in the post.

Answer (score 0):

just use **width** instead if *strokeWidth* =)